# IDE for java in google applications

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, netbeans

I would like to ask which IDE is preferably used in google applications for java. 
Netbeans or Eclipse?

Comment: Could you describe what kind of google applications mobile, web-gwt, etc.

Comment: I think that it's does not matter what you find as "accepted" we need here 1 answer per IDE and voting on it. It will show the most popular and not necessarily the best one though...

Comment: its a project management tool using scrum(web)

Answer (score 5):

You mean Google App Engine? Google supports [Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse.html). NetBeans plugin is fully community-driven.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Since Google officially use and publish Eclipse Plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Comment: There's an App Engine plugin for IntelliJ?

Comment: it works fine without any App Engine plugin (you can start, stop, debug GAE app, what else do you need?)

Comment: @yrlec, probably because most people don't trust to IDE that just works, without plugin :)

Answer (score 1):

The Google plugins for Eclipse are excellent and perform lots of checking on the client code to make sure that you are not using unemulated classes and that your ASync RPC interfaces correspond to your pure RPC interfaces (seamless). I have no experience of the Netbeans plugins but I imagine that they may be slightly behind the most recent releases as they are unsupported by Google.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new at using the Google app engine and I'm learning both Java and Python. I chose Eclipse because amount of tutorials I found on Youtube (Google IO videos) and the books I could download. Just my two cents but if you are learning on your own, I would use Eclipse.